# How do I get the search to use the attr_accessor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

Ok so i have a date field that i need to search on, but i need to search on it by day like in a mysql query

```
 search_conditions << ["DAY(open_date) != ?", event.thursday.day] if options[:thur].blank?
```

and i need to do this condition with Thinking Sphinx so i tried this

```
    attr_accessor :event_day

    def event_day
     self.start_date.day
    end

    #thinking sphinx configurations for the event search
    define_index do
     indexes event_day
     ...
     ...
```

and in the search i tried this

```
 search_string = "@event_day -#{event.thursday.day}" unless options[:thur].blank?
```

but i keep getting this error

```
index event_core: query error: no field 'event_day' found in schema
```

Any way to make this work

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a ruby attribute in an SQL query.  Rails isn't that clever.

You need to write SQL that replicates that function, or filter the results of a query through it, e.g.

```
@my_query.where(:a => "b").select { |rec| rec.some_method == "some value" }
```

Comment: not sure how that solves this situation...do i create a method that returns the day

Answer (score 0):

As Michael's pointed out, Ruby attributes aren't accessible by Sphinx - it talks directly to your database.

So, either you can create a column that holds the event day value, and reference that via Sphinx, or you can create a field that uses a SQL function (which could vary, depending on MySQL or PostgreSQL) that extracts the day from the start_date column - not particularly complex. It'd probably end up looking like this:

```
indexes "GET_DAY_FROM_DATE(start_date)", :as => :event_day
```